# Django - How to change placeholder of form in views

Tags: django, placeholder

How to change placeholder of form in views?

```
def myview(request):
    form = MyForm()
    form.widget.attrs.placeholder = 'Replace placeholder value'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set placeholder to form field dynamically:

```
def someview(request):
    form = SomeForm(..)

    if some_condition:
        form.fields['yourfield'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = instance.yourfield
```